# autocomplete in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to show the last input data filled by user in bootstrap modal, I tried using HTML autocomplete="on" attribute but failed, like done in this fiddle.

Once user click on submit, on the second time it shows the hints according to previous filled input values.

```
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-form-in-a-modal

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0fscmf3L/
```

Now I'm using jQuery autocomplete method but in that we have to pass an array as source. See following example

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Suppose I save the text input using ng-model or something and save data in $rootScope or scope and then I refresh the browser, then scope will get vanish.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose i save the text input using ng-model or something and save data in $rootScope or scope and then i refresh the browser, then scope will get vanish.

As you have said yourself, the values will not persist throughout your application because you will need to store values either in a database or in session variable for example.

Once you have done this you can then pass the array to your js code like below.

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = GetTags(); // GetTags() would be the method that gets your saved inputs.
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code Updated**
I suppose that you are using the second approach, i.e using angular js:
We could store the user input to the browser cookie and read from it.
Below is documentation for using angular cookie:
(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Below is the updated code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
var PageController = function($scope, $cookieStore) {
$scope.cookieList = $cookieStore.get('textName') || [];
$scope.storeDataToCookie = "";
$scope.totalCookie = 0;
$scope.getCookieList = function() {
    var arr = [];
    arr = $cookieStore.get("textName");
    $scope.cookieList = arr;
    $scope.totalCookie = $cookieStore.get("textName").length;
};
$scope.storeCookieData = function() {
    var array = $cookieStore.get('textName');
    if (array == null) {
        array = [];
    }
    array.push($scope.storeDataToCookie);
    $cookieStore.put('textName', array);
    $scope.cookieList = array;
    $scope.totalCookie = $cookieStore.get("textName").length;
};
$scope.deleteCookieData = function() {
    $cookieStore.remove('textName');
    $scope.cookieList = $cookieStore.get('textName') || [];
    $scope.totalCookie = 0;
};
$scope.retrieveCookieData = function() {
    //
    $scope.totalCookie = $cookieStore.get("textName").length;
};
}
myapp.controller('CookieTestController', PageController);
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="CookieTestController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="storeDataToCookie" />
        <input type="button" ng-click="storeCookieData()" value="Save Cookie Data" />
        <input type="button" ng-click="retrieveCookieData()" value="Retrieve Cookie Data" />
        <input type="button" ng-click="deleteCookieData()" value="Delete Cookie Data" />
        <input type="button" ng-click="getCookieList()" value="List Cookies" />
        <br />
        <span>Total Cookies:<strong>{{totalCookie}}</strong></span>
        <p>List of cookie values:</p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="c in cookieList">
                {{c}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the Plunker:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLcONnyle24vs5ZyiSBo?p=options)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: It is not showing any data in console on pressing Stored Cookie Data button, after giving input in text field and loosing focus.